Why the inverse of a specific matrix has a column with all same value?
Recently I observe an interesting result when dealing with the inverse matrix.
An $N\times N$ matrix $A$ has the following form:
\begin{pmatrix} &\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{X_{1i}} & -\frac{1}{X_{12}} & \ldots & -\frac{1}{X_{1N}} \\ & -\frac{1}{X_{21}} & \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{X_{2i}} & \ldots & -\frac{1}{X_{2N}} \\ &\vdots  &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\
&-\frac{1}{X_{N1}} & -\frac{1}{X_{N2}} & \ldots & \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{X_{Ni}}
\end{pmatrix}
That is, the nondiagonal element of this matrix is $-\frac{1}{X_{ij}}$ and the diagonal element equals the sum of all other elements in its row. Additionally, we assume $X_{ij} = X_{ji}$ that is $A$ is symmetric.
Of course this matrix is singular since its determinant is zero, by adding all columns to the first column then the first column will be all zero. To make $A$ invertible, we need modify it a little bit.
If we replace one diagonal element of $A$ by zero, for example the first one, then $A$ becomes
\begin{pmatrix} &0 & -\frac{1}{X_{12}} & \ldots & -\frac{1}{X_{1N}} \\ & -\frac{1}{X_{21}} & \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{X_{2i}} & \ldots & -\frac{1}{X_{2N}} \\ &\vdots  &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\
&-\frac{1}{X_{N1}} & -\frac{1}{X_{N2}} & \ldots & \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{X_{Ni}}
\end{pmatrix}
If necessary, we choose proper $\{X_{ij}\}$ such that the above matrix is invertible. I have tried some different values of $\{X_{ij}\}$ and observe that the first column of $A^{-1}$ always has the same value.
A simple example:
$A = \begin{pmatrix} &0 & -5 & -10 \\ & -5 & 10 & -5 \\ &-10 &-5 & 15 \end{pmatrix}$, the inverse $A^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} &-1/15 & -1/15 & -1/15 \\ & -1/15 & 4/75 & -2/75 \\ &-1/15 &-2/75 & 1/75 \end{pmatrix}$ where the first column is all $-1/15$.
So my question is whether the inverse of a matrix has the above form always has a column with all same value? If the answer is yes, how to prove it?
I tried to use adjoint matrix but failed to deal with the complicated equations.

You don't need to compute the inverse to check this. This condition says that $A^{-1} e_1$ is a multiple of $e_1 + \dots + e_n$ where $e_i$ is the standard basis. This is equivalent to the condition that $A(e_1 + \dots + e_n)$ is a multiple of $e_1$, which you can check.
